# Substring from position to position in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there an easy way to extract a string from a defined position to another defined position? (unlike the Substring Function where the last parameter is the length of the string being extracted).

Comment: length = pos2-pos1, doesn't it?

Comment: There is no "`EXTRACT`" function with the parameters `{Start Position}` and `{End Position}`. `SUBSTRING`, operates with `{Start Position}` and `{Number of Characters}`, just like most programming languages (I say most, as I'm sure there's an exception, I just don't know one). If you want a function like that, you'd have to write one (but why, I don't know, when `SUBSTRING` already serves the exact same purpose and the second parameter can easily be derived).

Answer (score 2):

Yep, basic maths:

```
declare @v varchar(200),
        @p1 int,
        @p2 int

select  @v = 'One Two Three',
        @p1 = 5,
        @p2 = 7

select  substring(@v, @p1, (@p2-@p1)+1)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I was actually looking for another function that I might not be familiar with ... But that should work for sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `@pos` and `@endpos`, you might find this useful:

```
select stuff(stuff(@str, @endpos + 1, len(@str), ''), 1, @pos - 1, '')
```

This eliminates the calculation of the length.